# Export Data from MSSQL to Excel and convert datetime to date

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

I built a query to export two columns of a table from a MSSQL database.
One column has the type `datetime`. I want to convert it into `date` before I put it into the Excel file.

When I want to import it into the MySQL database I get the error

> Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'dLieferdatum' at row 1")

and the `datetime` doesn't import into the MySQL column. But it does import when I change it manually to `date` in the Excel file.

My Code:

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import MySQLdb
import xlrd
import pymysql
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from datetime import datetime

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-XXXX\DEVELOPMENT;'
                      'Database=XXXXXXXXXX;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT cArtNr, dLieferdatum FROM XXXXXXXXXX.dbo.tLieferantenBestellungPos  WHERE dLieferdatum > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ')

for row in cursor:
    print(row.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

depts = ['cArtNr','dLieferdatum']
depts_query_string = "('{query_vals}')".format(query_vals="','".join(depts))

query = """
                            SELECT cArtNr, dLieferdatum
                            FROM XXXXXXXXXX.dbo.tLieferantenBestellungPos
                            WHERE dLieferdatum > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                            """.format(query_vals=depts_query_string)

target = r'O:\\Example'

P_data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
P_data.to_excel('C:\Datengrab\Python\Export.xlsx')

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Datengrab\Python\Export.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)



# MySQL Import Part
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX',
                             user='XXXXXXXX',
                             password='XXXXXXXXX',
                             db='XXXXXXX')



cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO XXXXXXXXX.jll99_deliverytime_import (cArtNr, dLieferdatum) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                cArtNr        = sheet.cell(r,1).value
                dLieferdatum  = sheet.cell(r,2).value


                values = (cArtNr, dLieferdatum)

                cursor.execute(query, values)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: How did you create the column `dLieferdatum`?

Comment: Just cast it in your query to date or char with the appropriate format.

Comment: And i'll note that you will eventually regret using 3 part names in your queries. The connection should determine the current database in which to run your query. If you need to use a different database (a very common task), you now have multiple places in your code to change.

Comment: I tried already to typecast the datetime to date, but I just don't know how. 
I doesn't work :-(

Maybe you know where in the code I need to change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query - CONVERT datetime to date does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910798/sql-query-convert-datetime-to-date-does-not-work)