# SQL Query - CONVERT datetime to date does not work

Tags: sql-server

Dears, do you know why below query doesn't work?
I want to convert the column dLieferdatum from `datetime` to `date` (2020-05-20)

```
SELECT dLieferdatum 
FROM dbo.tLieferantenBestellungPos 
WHERE dLieferdatum > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

Error message:

> Near ")", a non-Boolean expression was given in a context where a condition is expected.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to compare the date to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using `TRY_CONVERT()` is also an option:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dLieferdatum, 110) AS dLieferdatum 
FROM dbo.tLieferantenBestellungPos 
WHERE 
   (dLieferdatum > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND 
   (TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dLieferdatum, 110) IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I just tried it. The datetime column is still displayed as "2020-05-29 15:16:39.833"

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Please, check the updated answer, but why are using `GETDATE()`?

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you so much!!! Now it's working!!!
I'm a beginner beginner and try to learn all thy through google and stackoverflow... -.-' 
Excuse me if it's a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

This part of the select is not completed

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

it should be something  -->    value operator compared value

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) = '01/01/1900'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
Unfortunately I don't get any results now.. even though there should be at least 20 rows :-(

Comment: my reply was only in order to explain what whas the problem, surely you should rewrite the select anf provide correct values (or even remove this line if it doesn't apply)